# Clarification: R/Z or Q/Z

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was wondering what are these two groups: $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$. Thanks!

Comment: Quotient groups

Comment: Are you asking about the notation, or what those groups are? That's two different questions. The notation is the standard "quotient group" notation.

Comment: What the groups are.

Comment: Possible links: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/182247/visualizing-quotient-groups-mathbbr-q), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240298/show-that-bbb-q-bbb-z-is-an-infinite-group), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/240298/show-that-bbb-q-bbb-z-is-an-infinite-group) etc.

Answer (score 3):

These are the quotient groups of $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$ by the subgroup $\mathbb{Z}$.

Starting with real numbers or rational numbers, declare two numbers equivalent if their difference is an integer.  The equivalence classes under that relation form a group, called the quotient group.  Using set-theoretic notation, we say $x \sim y$ if $x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$, and then
$$
    \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z} = \left\{[x] \mid x\in\mathbb{R}\right\}
$$

More concretely, we cast off the “integer part” of every real/rational number.  This turns out to be consistent with additions.  For instance, if $[x]$ denotes the equivalent class of $x\in\mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{Z}$, then
$$
    [0.35] + [0.7] = [1.05] = [0.05]
$$

Comment: What is the set notation for it, I think I would understand it better that way. For instance, R/Z = {.... | ...}.

Comment: Do you know about equivalence relations, @user336012 ? It takes a little effort to get a good set notation for this, unfortunately.

Comment: @user336012: added in some set-theoretic stuff.

Comment: Note that both these groups have a more common interpretation in terms of rotations of the circle. $\Bbb R/\Bbb Z$ is the full group of rotations, while $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ is the group of rotations by a rational number of degrees.

Comment: @Arthur: that's a good point.